# Cannot find Entity Framework 4 annotations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, annotations

I'm trying to map a POCO class to a table of my DB using annotation.
I need to use `Table` annotation to specify the name of my table, but I cannot resolve the `Table` annotation.

Note: I imported `System.Data.Entity` namespace but It doesn't work.

Which namespace do I have to import to use EF annotations?

**NOTE 1**
I mean:

```
[Table("my_table")]
public class MyClass
{
    // ...
}
```

**NOTE 2** My Entity Framework dll is v4.0.30319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to use the `Table` annotation

You need to import the [System.Data.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515105.aspx) library, the [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) can be referenced from the `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` namespace.

Comment: I solved adding both `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and `System.Data.Linq` references and modifying annotation as `[Table(Name="my_table")]`. Thank you very much!

Comment: System.Data.Linq is not part of EF so it isnt needed

Answer (score 13):

You should import the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490428.aspx) namespace.

edit for .net 4.5 and EF 5.0: you should use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table` Attribute

Comment: I added the reference to my project and added `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to my class but it still doesn't work...

Comment: +1 I also added `System.Data.Linq` reference and now it works. thank you

Comment: System.Data.Linq.Mapping and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations both have Table and Column attribute classes, so it's not clear which one should be used.  They are different classes, and one excepts an explicity named parameter "Name" while the other does not.

Comment: @Triynko I think the `System.Data.Linq.*` namespace is used for Linq To SQL, whereas the question was about Entity Framework.

Comment: using System.ComponentModel and DisplayName is sufficient for diplaying the

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

and

```
[DisplayName("My friendly table name")]
```

Are sufficient to make it work with EF 5/6 and .Net 4.5, no need for *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations* namespace nor *System.Data.Linq* for these versions.

Comment: Above answer Satisfies for the EF targeted to the ,net framework <4.0.For  .net 4.5 and above namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema has table attribute which can be used to decorate the class as table attribute.