# Can I implement Entity Framework 5 TPT on Windows XP?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-5

Examples of **EF5 Table Per Type** that I have found, such as [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) use the `[Table("tablename")]` attribute to mark a class as defining a table.

When I add this attribute I get errors:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'TableAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    E:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.DomainClasses\Classes.cs    599 6   DomainClasses
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'TableAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    E:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.DomainClasses\Classes.cs    599 6   DomainClasses
```

I have the line

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

in my namespace

And I am using framework 4 because I want the app to run on Windows XP.

[Update] I had a look at the link flagged as a possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340733/cannot-find-entity-framework-4-annotations), and as a consequence added a reference to System.Data.Linq and a using System.Data.Linq

The error messages are now

```
 Error  1   The type or namespace name 'TableAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    E:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.DomainClasses\Classes.cs    599 6   DomainClasses
Error   2   Using the generic type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity>' requires 1 type arguments  E:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.DomainClasses\Classes.cs    599 6   DomainClasses
```

Importantly, I want my code to work on Windows XP , and the second answer to the possible duplicate requires framework 4.5

[Update] Code is as follows;

```
namespace SBD.Syrius.DomainClasses
{
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Data.Linq;

 [Table("Product")]
 public class Product : LoggedEntity
 { 
    [Required]
    public string BuyUnitMeasure { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal BuyUnitQuantity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String SellUnitMeasure { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal SellUnitQuantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UnitMeasure { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name) ? this.Name : "Products";
    }

}

 public abstract class LoggedEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int RowVersionId { get; set; }

    public int SourceSiteNumber { get; set; }

 }
}
```

[Update]

I corrected the using to be
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

Now my error is

```
 System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

[Update]

I also looked at the not accepted answer to the suggested duplicate question.  Which is to use  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations  however this requires framework 4.5 and I don't think I can use that because it wont run on Windows XP, and I need to run on XP.

[update]
[image: Here is the screen in Manage Nuget Packages]

[image: Here is the reference in my project]

I am developing on Windows 7 but the application needs to run on XP.
I see the example I am trying to follow 
[Here it is again](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)  uses Framework 4.1 Fluent

My question is Can I use TPT on EF5 to run on Windows XP?
If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find Entity Framework 4 annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340733/cannot-find-entity-framework-4-annotations). If not, show the exact error, when it happens and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: @CodeCaster, i have updated the question. I don't think it is a duplicate -as explained in my update

Comment: You're using `System.Data.Linq.Table`, not `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute`. It's still a duplicate: you're having the exact same problem.

Comment: @Codecaster I tried changing as you suggest , but still have an error. I updated the question with the additional information.

Comment: Take a look at the *not* accepted answer in the duplicate question which has the correct solution. The accepted answer is just plain wrong because `System.Data.Linq` is a LINQ-to-SQL and not an EF namespace.

Comment: Thanks @Slauma , I am glad you pointed out the accepted answer is plain wrong , I had thought that but am starting to feel scared of asking "silly questions".  I updated the question with why I cant use the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, remove the `System.Data.Linq` namespace and don't use the `TableAttribute` from there. It is for LINQ-to-SQL and not for Entity Framework.

Between version 4.1 and 5.0 of Entity Framework the `Table` attribute (among others) has been moved around a bit between namespaces **and** assemblies:

Depending on the version you can find the attribute at the follwing places:

#### Entity Framework 4.1 to 4.3 and target framework .NET 4.0

- Add reference to `EntityFramework.dll` assembly to your project
- Add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` to code file

#### Entity Framework 5.0 and target framework .NET 4.0 (This combination is also called Entity Framework 4.4)

- Add reference to `EntityFramework.dll` assembly to your project
- Add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` to code file

#### Entity Framework 5.0 and target framework .NET 4.5

- Add reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly to your project
- Add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` to code file

The `TableAttribute` has kept its old purpose and meaning in all versions. Especially it's the correct one to use for TPT.

In your situation where you want to support Windows XP but use EF 5.0 you need .NET 4.0 as target framework. To get the correct `TableAttribute` you have to do:

- Add reference to `EntityFramework.dll` assembly to your project (most likely you have that already)
- Check if this DLL (right mouse -> Properties) has version number 4.4. You can potentially have the wrong version (5.0) if you downloaded the Nuget package while your project targetted .NET 4.5. and you changed the framework later to .NET 4.0. In that case remove the reference to the current `EntityFramework.dll` and add a reference to the `EntityFramework.dll` assembly in the path `packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40` under your solution folder
- Add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` to code file

Start with the last of these three points, maybe it's your only problem that you have to append `.Schema` to the `using` directive.

Comment: Thanks, this looks right. My code is calling a lot of things in EntityFramework 5.0, so it will take me some time to get it working.

Comment: Still working on it...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991766/how-can-i-implement-dbset-addorupdate-in-entity-framework-4-4

Answer (score 4):

The class you are trying to use [is new to Entity Framework 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.aspx). You can't use Entity Framework 5 on XP because it requires .NET 4.5. The reason you are getting the errors is NuGet likely downloaded Entity Framework 4.4.

What the properties look like when you download it from NuGet from a .NET 4.0 project

[image]

What the properties look like when you download it from NuGet from a .NET 4.5 project

[image]

Your only two options are

1. Don't use `TableAttribute`
2. Don't support XP

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me where you took the screen dumps from? I took some screen dumps too and updated the question.

Comment: @kirsteng I opened a 4.0 project went to NuGet and downloaded the project then clicked on `references` and opened the `properties` page for the dll it downloaded. I then did the same thing with a 4.5 project.